# Extract the value using regular expression in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract 'Processed & Soft Cheese1' from the below response:

`1.)"departments":["Processed & Soft Cheese1"],`

I am trying `departments":["(.+?)"`, but it doesn't work.

Can some one please help to create regex for the same

Comment: Could you please remove the `java` and `performance-testing` tags?

Comment: Escape `[`..... If the `.+?` gives you trouble, replace with `[^"]+`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very bad description of your problem, because it doesn't give us information about level of your understanding, not to mention a lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to escape the `[` like `\[`

[`departments":\["(.+?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/OL33rn/1/)